# XSL complicated transform with sorting, adding and removing elements

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm trying to transform an XML document using XSLT but I'm having difficulties because there are multiple processing tasks to be performed on the XML document.

Here are the steps I'm looking to accomplish (sorry, I'm not sure if this is even possible or if I'll have to try some other means):

1 - strip/remove all `<group>` elements and put/move the adjacent `<relation>` element into the next `<filter>` element

2 - sort all the `<filter>` elements by two elements within called `<relation>` and `<filtertype>`

3 - re-group all the `<filter>` elements by `<relation>` and by `<filtertype>` by adding back the `<group>` elements and pulling the `<relation>` element out of the the first `<filter>` element in the `<group>`

In other words, I'm attempting to undo all the existing grouping, sort all filter elements  by like filtertype and relation and then re-group the filters by common filtertype and relation knowing that the first group element must have a relation element that is moved from it's first filter element into the group element

Sorry if that's confusing, my sample is below (thanks in advance)

**INPUT XML**

```
<mainXML>
   <version major="1" minor="0" build="0" revision="0"/>
   <id>30</id>
   <set>Partial</set>
   <evaluate>True</evaluate>
   <group>
      <relation>And</relation>
      <filter>
         <filtertype>Search</filtertype>
         <attributeid>32900</attributeid>
         <action>
            <type>Numeric</type>
            <operator>GreaterThanOrEqualTo</operator>
            <value>01001</value>
         </action>
      </filter>
      <filter>
         <relation>Or</relation>
         <filtertype>Search</filtertype>
         <attributeid>32900</attributeid>
         <action>
            <type>Numeric</type>
            <operator>LessThanOrEqualTo</operator>
            <value>26886</value>
         </action>
      </filter>
   </group>
   <group>
      <relation>Or</relation>
      <filter>
         <filtertype>Search</filtertype>
         <attributeid>32900</attributeid>
         <action>
            <type>Numeric</type>
            <operator>GreaterThanOrEqualTo</operator>
            <value>30001</value>
         </action>
      </filter>
   </group>
   <group>
      <relation>And</relation>
      <filter>
         <filtertype>Grouping</filtertype>
         <action>
            <type>Mailing</type>
            <operator>DoNotBelongTo</operator>
            <groupingid>1133519</groupingid>
         </action>
      </filter>
      <filter>
         <relation>And</relation>
         <filtertype>Action</filtertype>
         <campaign>
            <campaignid>1509779</campaignid>
         </campaign>
         <action>
            <status>DoNot</status>
            <operator>Bill</operator>
         </action>
         <operator>AfterNHour</operator>
         <value>36</value>
      </filter>
      <filter>
         <relation>Or</relation>
         <filtertype>Action</filtertype>
         <campaign>
            <campaignid>1509779</campaignid>
         </campaign>
         <action>
            <status>DoNot</status>       
         </action>
         <operator>AfterNHour</operator>
         <value>36</value>
      </filter>
   </group>
</mainXML>
```

**Desired Output XML**

```
<mainXML>
   <version major="1" minor="0" build="0" revision="0"/>
   <id>30</id>
   <set>Partial</set>
   <evaluate>True</evaluate>
   <group>
      <relation>And</relation>
      <filter>
         <filtertype>Action</filtertype>
         <campaign>
            <campaignid>1509779</campaignid>
         </campaign>
         <action>
            <status>DoNot</status>
            <operator>Bill</operator>
         </action>
         <operator>AfterNHour</operator>
         <value>36</value>
      </filter>
   </group>
   <group>
      <relation>Or</relation>
      <filter>
         <filtertype>Action</filtertype>
         <campaign>
            <campaignid>1509779</campaignid>
         </campaign>
         <action>
            <status>DoNot</status>
         </action>
         <operator>AfterNHour</operator>
         <value>36</value>
      </filter>
   </group>
   <group>
      <relation>And</relation>
      <filter>
         <filtertype>Grouping</filtertype>
         <action>
            <type>Mailing</type>
            <operator>DoNotBelongTo</operator>
            <groupingid>1133519</groupingid>
         </action>
      </filter>
   </group>
   <group>
      <relation>And</relation>
      <filter>
         <filtertype>Search</filtertype>
         <attributeid>32900</attributeid>
         <action>
            <type>Numeric</type>
            <operator>GreaterThanOrEqualTo</operator>
            <value>01001</value>
         </action>
      </filter>
   </group>
   <group>
      <relation>Or</relation>
      <filter>
         <filtertype>Search</filtertype>
         <attributeid>32900</attributeid>
         <action>
            <type>Numeric</type>
            <operator>LessThanOrEqualTo</operator>
            <value>26886</value>
         </action>
      </filter>
      <filter>
         <relation>Or</relation>
         <filtertype>Search</filtertype>
         <attributeid>32900</attributeid>
         <action>
            <type>Numeric</type>
            <operator>GreaterThanOrEqualTo</operator>
            <value>30001</value>
         </action>
      </filter>
   </group>
</mainXML>
```

Answer (score 0):

**This transformation:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kFilterRel" match="filter"
  use="concat(filtertype,'+'
              , (preceding-sibling::*[1]
                            [self::relation]
               | relation
                )[1]
              )"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
  <xsl:param name="pPos"/>
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*">
     <xsl:with-param name="pPos" select="$pPos"/>
   </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|*[not(self::group)]"/>

   <xsl:apply-templates select=
     "*/filter
        [generate-id()
        =
         generate-id(key('kFilterRel',
                         concat(filtertype,'+'
                                , (preceding-sibling::*[1]
                                             [self::relation]
                                  | relation
                                  )[1]
                               )
                         )
                         [1]
                     )]">
    <xsl:sort select="filtertype"/>
    <xsl:sort select="(preceding-sibling::*[1]
                                   [self::relation]
                     | relation)[last()]"/>
   </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="filter">
  <group>
    <xsl:variable name="vRelation"
        select="(preceding-sibling::*[1][self::relation]
               | relation)[last()]"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="$vRelation"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="inGroup" select=
     "key('kFilterRel',
          concat(filtertype,'+'
                 , (preceding-sibling::relation[1]
                   | relation
                   )[last()]
                )
         )">
       <xsl:with-param name="pRel" select="$vRelation"/>
     </xsl:apply-templates>
  </group>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="filter" mode="inGroup">
  <xsl:param name="pRel"/>

  <filter>
      <xsl:if test="not(relation) and position() > 1">
       <xsl:copy-of select="$pRel"/>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:apply-templates>
       <xsl:with-param name="pPos" select="position()"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
  </filter>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="relation">
  <xsl:param name="pPos"/>

  <xsl:if test="$pPos > 1">
   <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<mainXML>
   <version major="1" minor="0" build="0" revision="0"/>
   <id>30</id>
   <set>Partial</set>
   <evaluate>True</evaluate>
   <group>
      <relation>And</relation>
      <filter>
         <filtertype>Search</filtertype>
         <attributeid>32900</attributeid>
         <action>
            <type>Numeric</type>
            <operator>GreaterThanOrEqualTo</operator>
            <value>01001</value>
         </action>
      </filter>
      <filter>
         <relation>Or</relation>
         <filtertype>Search</filtertype>
         <attributeid>32900</attributeid>
         <action>
            <type>Numeric</type>
            <operator>LessThanOrEqualTo</operator>
            <value>26886</value>
         </action>
      </filter>
   </group>
   <group>
      <relation>Or</relation>
      <filter>
         <filtertype>Search</filtertype>
         <attributeid>32900</attributeid>
         <action>
            <type>Numeric</type>
            <operator>GreaterThanOrEqualTo</operator>
            <value>30001</value>
         </action>
      </filter>
   </group>
   <group>
      <relation>And</relation>
      <filter>
         <filtertype>Grouping</filtertype>
         <action>
            <type>Mailing</type>
            <operator>DoNotBelongTo</operator>
            <groupingid>1133519</groupingid>
         </action>
      </filter>
      <filter>
         <relation>And</relation>
         <filtertype>Action</filtertype>
         <campaign>
            <campaignid>1509779</campaignid>
         </campaign>
         <action>
            <status>DoNot</status>
            <operator>Bill</operator>
         </action>
         <operator>AfterNHour</operator>
         <value>36</value>
      </filter>
      <filter>
         <relation>Or</relation>
         <filtertype>Action</filtertype>
         <campaign>
            <campaignid>1509779</campaignid>
         </campaign>
         <action>
            <status>DoNot</status>
         </action>
         <operator>AfterNHour</operator>
         <value>36</value>
      </filter>
   </group>
</mainXML>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<mainXML>
   <version major="1" minor="0" build="0" revision="0"/>
   <id>30</id>
   <set>Partial</set>
   <evaluate>True</evaluate>
   <group>
      <relation>And</relation>
      <filter>
         <filtertype>Action</filtertype>
         <campaign>
            <campaignid>1509779</campaignid>
         </campaign>
         <action>
            <status>DoNot</status>
            <operator>Bill</operator>
         </action>
         <operator>AfterNHour</operator>
         <value>36</value>
      </filter>
   </group>
   <group>
      <relation>Or</relation>
      <filter>
         <filtertype>Action</filtertype>
         <campaign>
            <campaignid>1509779</campaignid>
         </campaign>
         <action>
            <status>DoNot</status>
         </action>
         <operator>AfterNHour</operator>
         <value>36</value>
      </filter>
   </group>
   <group>
      <relation>And</relation>
      <filter>
         <filtertype>Grouping</filtertype>
         <action>
            <type>Mailing</type>
            <operator>DoNotBelongTo</operator>
            <groupingid>1133519</groupingid>
         </action>
      </filter>
   </group>
   <group>
      <relation>And</relation>
      <filter>
         <filtertype>Search</filtertype>
         <attributeid>32900</attributeid>
         <action>
            <type>Numeric</type>
            <operator>GreaterThanOrEqualTo</operator>
            <value>01001</value>
         </action>
      </filter>
   </group>
   <group>
      <relation>Or</relation>
      <filter>
         <filtertype>Search</filtertype>
         <attributeid>32900</attributeid>
         <action>
            <type>Numeric</type>
            <operator>LessThanOrEqualTo</operator>
            <value>26886</value>
         </action>
      </filter>
      <filter>
         <relation>Or</relation>
         <filtertype>Search</filtertype>
         <attributeid>32900</attributeid>
         <action>
            <type>Numeric</type>
            <operator>GreaterThanOrEqualTo</operator>
            <value>30001</value>
         </action>
      </filter>
   </group>
</mainXML>
```